# Removing unused factors from a facet_grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've this df:

```
    df <- data.frame(
      id = c(rep(1:3,20), rep(4:6,20)),
      type = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=3, times=10),
      timing = rep(c("T0","T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), each=12, times=2),
      group = rep(c("Case","Control"),each=60),
      percentage = runif(120, min=15, max=25)
    )
```

`scale="free"` or `scale="free_y"` dosen't work producing this bar plot:

```
  require(scales)
   ggplot(df, aes(x=id, y=percentage, fill=type)) +
   facet_grid(group ~ timing,scale="free") +
   geom_bar(position="stack",aes(width = 0.5),stat = "identity") +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
   coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of `df`, so people can develop and test solutions. The `dput` function is useful for that.

Comment: if they're factors, can' you use droplevels?

Comment: As Russ said, try `ggplot(droplevels(df), aes(x=ID, y=percentage, fill=type))`

Comment: @RussHyde "droplevels" seems doesn't work

Comment: @docendodiscimus "droplevels" seems doesn't work